# Cambiar color a un Textinputarea

Tags: java, android, android-studio, input

Tengo este edittext dentro de un textinputar

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout


         android:id="@+id/TIL_Tres"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:buttonTint="#d2b662"
                        android:backgroundTint="#d2b662"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textColorHint="#d2b662"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/Correo"
                            android:layout_width="250dp"
                            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
                            android:backgroundTint="#d2b662"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:hint="Correo"
                            android:textColor="#d2b662"
                            android:imeActionId="6"
                            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense"
                            android:imeActionLabel="Correo"
                            android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:singleLine="true" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento de escribir cambia al color del tema que tiene la aplicación. ¿Como puedo editar este color?

Tengo entendido que en el `colors.xml` de la carpeta values que te crea el proyecto se debería editar, pero no me funciona.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#d2b662</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#d2b662</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#D81B60</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: podrias buscar el archivo styles.xml..

Comment: referencia: https://www.android-examples.com/change-textinputlayout-underline-color-in-android-example-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el AndroidManifest.xml existe una linea llamada android:theme="@style/AppTheme"> que es la que decide que colores utilizar con base a el estilo que utilices. Solo se tiene que cambiar el color en el el Styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

y yap, espero que a alguien le sirva aun que no este del todo explicado.